# Problem in splitting single column values into multiple column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

On Friday I posted a question regarding splitting single column values to multiple column values I got somoe problems there and now in my source table I got some new feilds added and the tale looks somthing like this:

For Example:

```
Name
---------------------      
abcd efgh      
ijk lmn     
opq  asd j. asdjja      
asb (asdfas) asd      
asd     
john  tronton III    
john    bradly  0    
user
```

and expecting output something like this:

```
first_name             last_name  
-----------            ------------------
abcd                     efgh       
ijk                      lmn
opq                      asdjja      
asb                      asd      
asd                      null     
john                      tronton III    
john                      bradly    
null                      null (because user is not the name)
```

Need the query in Select statement

The middle name can be omitted (no need for a middle name) The columns are already created and need to insert the data from that single 'Name' column.

Thanks a lot,

Shahsra

Comment: You've got enough rep to know how to format your question -- the more readable it is, the more likely to be answered...

Comment: could you please tell me where you did not understand so that I can explain you my question?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look at the answer to this question...

[Extracting First Name and Last Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145791/extracting-first-name-and-last-name)

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH Split_Names (Name, xmlname)
AS
(
    SELECT 
    Name,
    CONVERT(XML,'<Names><name>'  
    + REPLACE(Name,' ', '</name><name>') + '</name></Names>') AS xmlname
      FROM somenames
)

 SELECT       
 xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[1]','varchar(100)') AS first_name,    
 xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[2]','varchar(100)') AS last_name
 FROM Split_Names
```

and also check the link below for reference

http://jahaines.blogspot.in/2009/06/converting-delimited-string-of-values.html