# Extracting First Name and Last Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a column named Name in a table called test which has Full name and I am trying to extract First name and Last Name. So I wrote query something like this:

```
SELECT 
[Name],
 LEFT([Name],CHARINDEX(' ',[Name])-1)  AS FIRST_NAME,
SUBSTRING([Name],CHARINDEX(' ',[Name])+1,LEN([Name])) AS LAST_NAME
FROM Test
```

But It is giving me error saying:

Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Thta's because I have some values in the name like:

Name:

Hopkins

How do I handle these?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Declare @t table ( [Name] varchar(100) )

insert into @t ( Name )
VALUES ( 'dennis hopper' ), ('keanu reaves'), ('thatgirl') 

SELECT
    [Name],
    CHARINDEX(' ', [Name]),
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', [Name]) > 0 THEN
        LEFT([Name],CHARINDEX(' ',[Name])-1)
    ELSE
        [Name]
    END as FIRST_NAME,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', [Name]) > 0 THEN
        SUBSTRING([Name],CHARINDEX(' ',[Name])+1, ( LEN([Name]) - CHARINDEX(' ',[Name])+1) )
    ELSE
        NULL
    END as LAST_NAME
FROM @t
```

Comment: In this case I am getting firstName and Last name as Hopkins I want First name as Hopkins and Lastname as Null

Comment: I got it I just replcaed the else part in last name with Null. Thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your original code is here:

```
CHARINDEX(' ',[Name])-1
```

If [Name] does not contain a space, CharIndex returns 0.  You subtract 1 and feed this in to the Left function. When the 2nd parameter to the left function is -1, you will get this error.  In my opinion, the easiest way to "fix" this problem is to give the CharIndex function something to find, like this:

```
CHARINDEX(' ',[Name] + ' ')-1
```

Now... this code cannot fail.

You only NEED to do this one place in your original code, but you should add it to the LAST_NAME part also.  If you don't, you will get incorrect results (eventhough you will not get an error).

```
SELECT [Name],
       LEFT([Name],CHARINDEX(' ',[Name] + ' ')-1)  AS FIRST_NAME,
       SUBSTRING([Name],CHARINDEX(' ',[Name] + ' ')+1,LEN([Name])) AS LAST_NAME
FROM   Test
```

This query will return the same results as the query suggested by @Sage, but (in my opinion) it is easier to read, and easier to understand.

Answer (score -4):

we may also use locate function

SELECT 
Name,
 LEFT(Name,locate(' ',Name)-1)  AS FIRST_NAME,
SUBSTRING(Name,locate(' ',Name)+1,LENgth(Name)) AS LAST_NAME
FROM test

Comment: This question is about SQL Server, not MySQL.