# Swap first name and last names in a column using SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005

How do I change the first name and last name from a given name, for example: I have a name "Krishna Kiran" with Krishna as the first name and Kiran as the last name (surname) in a column.

Now I need the output as "Kiran, Krishna", that is, `lastname, firstname`. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting First Name and Last Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145791/extracting-first-name-and-last-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145791/extracting-first-name-and-last-name)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ISNULL(LastName + ', ', '') 
       + ISNULL(FirstName, '') AS FormattedName FROM ...
```

Comment: well i have column called as author, which contains a value say "Stieg Larsson" i should re populate it as  Larsson, Stieg

Comment: yes they are not separated and i need to repopulate them into the same column or in a different column

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @T table (Name varchar(50))

insert into @T values ('krishna kiran')

select
  right(Name, len(Name)-charindex(' ', Name, 0))+', '+left(Name, charindex(' ', Name, 0))
from @T
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

`UPDATE TableName set first_name=(@temp:=first_name),first_name=last_name,last_name=@temp;`

refer the image :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri2AU.jpg